# select2 gem remember selected options after search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, jquery-select2

I have used `select2` gem in my rails 6 project to show multiple options to select

`<%= select_tag 'skill[]', options_for_select(Course.populate_data, :selected=> "#{params[:skill] rescue nil}"), :prompt => "skill", class: "form-control js-select",id: "js-skill", :style => "width:180px", multiple: "multiple", :style => "width:280px;"%>&nbsp;&nbsp;`

I want selectbox to remember my last selections after I submitted the search form

I tried data amd params, but not working for me, can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, using below code. I was not doing `AJAX` call, otherwise I would have done this in `success response of query`

```
$(".js-select").select2();
if ("<%=params[:skill]%>") {
  var a = <%=raw params[:skill]%>
  $('#js-skill').select2().val(a).trigger('change');
} else {
  $("#js-skill").select2();
}
```

Posting the answer, if it may help someone